# Gradle define security policy for tests

Tags: java, junit, gradle, security-policy

I want to pass a security manager to be used in Junit tests by gradle.
I tried jvmargs(not working) and now I'm using this:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

test {
  systemProperties << ['java.security.policy': file("$projectDir/security.policy").absolutePath]
}

...
```

Java class

```
package hello;

import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*; 

public class MyClass {
  public void method() {
    try {
        File file = new File("/etc/passwd");
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        char [] a = new char[50];
        fr.read(a);
        for(char c : a)
           System.out.print(c);
        fr.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

My policy is:

```
grant {
    permission java.io.FilePermission "/home/-", "read";
};
```

So I expect to get security exception when trying to read `/etc/passwd` but I don't.

Comment: And? What's the result of this attempt?

Comment: The class outputs line from /etc/passwd it's supposed not to

Answer (score 1):

The [Gradle User Guide section 46.2.3](https://docs.gradle.org/4.2.1/userguide/tutorial_java_projects.html#javaQuickstart) has an example on setting a system property for a test which differs from yours:

```
test {
    systemProperties 'property': 'value'
}
```

Perhaps you can try with that syntax, which would be

```
test {
    systemProperties 'java.security.policy': file("$projectDir/security.policy").absolutePath
}
```